# How to solve preview bug in SwiftUI? [XCode 13]

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, mapkit, accent-color

I am using a `mapkit` element and want to see the preview. But, the preview option provided by Xcode is showing wrong color for map annotations.

For example, If I set annotation color as yellow, In preview I'm getting blue color.

Sample code:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: locations, annotationContent: { item in
            // a. Old style, always static
            MapPin(coordinate: item.location, tint: .accentColor)
        })
```

Note my accent color is: yellow.

Is there any solution to solve this preview bug?

Comment: Show your sample code which you've tried so far.
As I'm not facing any color difference in preview screen as well as on device

Comment: Shared above. Please have a look.

Comment: I tried your code and is running fine in both simulator and in preview.

Comment: Are you using xcode 13.2.1? And did you changed accentColor to yellow from assets directory?

Comment: @Ronak, If you use default accent color without changing it, you will not be able to create the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I have found that there is no problem in the code.

It can be a bug of XCode 13.2.1's preview system. Because I have got the correct output using simulator without changing anything in the code. So, nothing to worry at all if you face this kind of issue sometimes.

Still, if anyone have anything to share on top my answer, you are welcome.